# enabling both api and web app in same repository with vercel deployement

Tags: javascript, python, flask, vite, vercel

I am working on a project with a frontend app developped with Vitejs and a backend develop with Python/Flask. Both the frontend and the backend are colocated in the same repository. I am aiming to deploy this project with Vercel. To do so, I have configured my vercel.json file in this manner :

```
{
 "rewrites": [
  {
  "source": "/api/(.*)",
  "destination": "/api"
  },
  {
  "source": "/:path((?!api/).*)",
  "destination": "/"
  }
 ]
}
```

This way, frontend app can be reach from any request that does not match "/api" path. request on "/api" path are led to the python code.

- It works fine for the frontend part. For the backend part, it seems that requests to "/api" are stilled handled by the frontend
- how should I make request to backend ? in local environment, I can call the backend at the "localhost:5000" address. Should it work too when deployed on Vercel (which I suppose not to)?

1. link to the code: https://github.com/frederic-lang/awesome-konva-react-demos
2. link to the deployed app: https://awesome-konva-react-demos.vercel.app/
3. api handled by the frontend link: https://awesome-konva-react-demos.vercel.app/api/etat_cube